# modify set-cookie header chrome extenstion in manifest v3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have a use case where my old extension contains code that will add `; SameSite=None; Secure` to the `set-cookie` header for iframe's. like the below code
`

```
 event.responseHeaders.forEach((header) => {
      if (header.name.toLowerCase() === "set-cookie") {
        header.value = header.value + "; SameSite=None; Secure"
      }
    });
```

`

I need an equivalent in manfifest v3
I have tried

```
{
      id: 2,
      priority: 1,
      action: {
        type: "modifyHeaders",
        responseHeaders: [
          {
            header: "Set-Cookie",
            operation: "append",
            value: "'SameSite=None; Secure'",
          },
        ],
      },
      condition: {
        urlFilter: "*",
        resourceTypes: ["sub_frame"],
      },
    },
```

And it is not doing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not implemented: https://crbug.com/1254637.

- The `append` operation for **responseHeaders** just [adds a new header](https://crsrc.org/extensions/browser/api/web_request/web_request_api_helpers.cc;l=540;drc=caa1747121ee9f14ba7d4e346ea2dc5e7a2e05c0;bpv=1;bpt=1) with this name and value.
- The `append` operation for **requestHeaders** appends the value via a delimiter in [supported headers](https://crsrc.org/extensions/browser/api/declarative_net_request/constants.h;l=250;drc=d377adec687d1d631fe7fea246706b51fdfea368). Implemented since Chrome 108, previously an error was shown.